# Orange Environment in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine5

I created a new Third-Person game on Unreal Engine Version 5.0.3. The walls, the ground, and the ramp is organe - unlike the tutorials in which they are grey.
[Here is what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knr4Q.jpg)
[And here is what it should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msaWN.jpg)

I decreased the Skylight intensity (got the idea from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/u091iy/ue5_lighting_is_orange/) but it made everything too dark and still does not match the tutorials.  (couldnt upload scrnshot because it was too large)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was just messing around, and apparently I need to add another Skylight to fix it. Hope this helps in case you are having similar issues.